# ResetPasswordAsync fails with Invalid Token error in Asp.net core 2.1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

In my Asp.Net Core 2.1 Web Api + Angular App setup, I am trying to reset user password token using identity framework. Token is generated by calling GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(), emailed and request is sent back from client, verified by ResetPasswordAsync. I have checked that the two tokens are same but still ResetPasswordAsync fails with Invalid Token result.

I am using PG SQL as database, and JWT for Authentication, The SecurityStamp is also not null, my client app is written in angular and served from a different web server than the one serving the web api. However when testing on local machine there is no problem.

I have enabled CORS in web api allowing any origin, however I have noticed that my client request contain
Origin: `https://my-domain.com`
Referer: `https://my-domain.com/myangularapp`

Please let me know if any info is missing, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: iamadnan did you get this resolved?

Comment: Yes, I just specified a provider for it instead of using default.
`services.AddIdentity<MyType>, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    ...........................
   ............................
   options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = "TokenProvider"; 
}`

Comment: Actually  there were two problems, so in case it was related to the sub-domain, it was due to absence of this
`corsBuilder.SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();`
The other problem was with the wrong type code it was generating.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at my issue!